# when does session id changes?

Tags: php, codeigniter

something weird is happening on the website I am doing. Per the forums I've read, session ids don't change even we refresh or reload the page. Which is correct. The thing is, my session id is changing for some records when I click Edit (to go to edit mode) some are not.

This is the scenario happening. I will view record A. Then click Edit button. All fields are populating correctly since my session id did not change.

But when I view record B and click edit, all fields became blank. Upon checking, my session id changed.

all action, validation and so on (except for data on backend, of course), A and B are the same. I don't know why everytime I edit record B, session id changes while record A doesn't.

Any idea when does session id changes?

Im using this by the way:

```
$this->session->userdata('session_id')
```

Comment: `session_regenerate_id()`

Comment: I also tried this:
`$this->session->set_userdata('session_id', session_id())`

session id doesnt change anymore. But there is no session id is generated on my first load. I called session_start before this.

Comment: How do you use `$this->session->userdata('session_id')` in your app?

Comment: I just get the value of '$this->session->userdata('session_id')' and save it on DB because I need a unique ID on the record I am modifying. This is to avoid users on modifying the exact same record.

Answer (score 1):

In `/application/config/config.php` ,check the `$config['sess_time_to_update']` value.

Increase the time if needed.

Comment: session id is regenerated after every few minz.You can create a uniqui id for your work and save it in session.I think this may do your work

Comment: Session id hash is updated every 5 minz according to the Codeigniter documentation